# Custom Logging Request & Response in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I understand that WSO2 API Manager provides features to configure logging/tracing of incoming request.
Is there a way to generate custom logs, which captures the following :-

1. URL of the services invoked.
2. Request parameters - JSON.
3. Time of the request.

We only intend to make a record of all the request made to our services. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Following are two options you can use

1. Add [log mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Log+Mediator) to log message. You can create a  [custom sequence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+Mediation+Extensions) and deploy that mediator. Logs will be in wso2carbon.log
2. Read the http_access logs. Http access logs are written in /repository/logs location. It contains the request, access time, etc.